# Jquery to insert all body elements into a <Main> tag

Tags: html, jquery, accessibility

I do not know anything about Jquery and would really appreciate some help or direction.

I am looking to insert all  tags inside a  tag into a singular  tag for accessibility purposes.

The website in question is built inside a CMS(Sitefinity 14.2) where all HTML is inside a  tag. Refer to below screenshots. I need to exclude all scripts and only have the  tags between the Header and Footer tag inserted in the main tag.

Currently it looks like this:

```html
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
  <script>
  <header>
  <div>
  <div>
  <div>
  <footer>
  <script>
  <script>
</body>
```

Whereas i am aiming for it to look like this:

```html
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
  <script>
  <header>
    <main>
      <div>
      <div>
      <div>
     </main>
  <footer>
  <script>
  <script>
</body>
```

Below is a screenshot of the HTML.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

[Raw HTML from Home page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4CLz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('div:not(header *,footer *)').wrapAll('<main>')
```

```css
header {
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow
}

footer {
height: 100px;
background-color: green
}

main {
height: 150px;
background-color: blue
}

main .child-div {
background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div>
<h2>Header is not included in main, it's yellow</h2>
</div>
</header>
<div class="child-div">Main Div 1, Main is blue, But .child-div class is red</div>
<div>Main Div 2, Main is blue</div>
<div>Main Div 3, Main is blue</div>
<footer><div>
<h2>Header is not included in main, it's green</h2>
</div></footer>
```

### Explanation

Additional to @j08691, if you want to only include divs that are not already wrapped by  or , use the [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) `:not()` combine with jQuery. Basic about `:not()` [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp).

Since you have to ***Select `div` that are not (!) children/descendants of `header` or `footer`*** and W3School only gives you a little basic about this, I'd like to explain a little bit further.

```css
/* Select elements that are
   not paragraphs */
:not(p) { /* ... */ }

/* Select paragraphs that
   don't have the class "fancy" */
p:not(.fancy) { /* ... */ }

/* Select elements that are
   not p or span */
:not(p):not(span) { /* ... */ }

/* Select elements that are
   not p or span */
:not(p, span) { /* ... */ }
```

Dive deeper into the [Specification of CSS Selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#complex), you'll see that it's possible to  select elements that are not (!) children/descendants of other elements using the universal selector `(*)`. And that gives you the result `div:not(header *,footer *)`

Comment: Just one more thing @Bao. This script seems to replace every single div which then in turn removes all the classes. Is there a way to not change the classes at all? Instead creating a new element and placing every div inside it without overriding the parental divs? Thanks. Im mucking around with it now but cant really seem to figure out a correct way.

Comment: I don't quite understand your concern. I've just updated the code, run it as you can see the class `.child-div` is still there and make the background change to another color

Answer (score 0):

`$('div').wrapAll('<main>')` would do it:

```js
$('div').wrapAll('<main>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Doc: https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

Comment: It wraps all, but I am only wanting to include divs that are not already wrapped by a <header> or <footer> tag, and then store it in between the two.

Comment: I am trying to use one of the methods in the link you shared but cant seem to get it.   ( "div" ).wrapAll( document.createElement( "main" ) ); Just keeps erroring me